# Error logging in Lightdm - Hera 5.1

Tags: greeter, release-hera

> 'Unable to Log In
>   Starting the sessions has failed.
>
> Erro -> Session returned -> error code 1'

Using gdm3 I can log in normally, with Lightdm that Elementary uses I can't log in.

I already reinstalled the elementary desktop and the error persists, has anyone gone through it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmSz7.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

The error, I suppose, sits in Ubunta and there is no solution or no one knows how to fix it. I sit with the same trouble.

Comment: Edited the answer above. Check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check who is the owner of .Xauthority file. It should be a user instead of root.

Press ctrl alt and F1 for example. Login. Then type

```
cd /home/username
```

Username of course is the name of the user you are using to login to system.
Then type

```
ls -al
```

You will see who is the owner of the .Xauthority.
If root root
then type

```
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

Then type

```
sudo reboot
```

After that you should be able to login.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.